# How to style movable tab in QTabWidget

Tags: python, qt, pyqt, qtstylesheets

I got most of the styling done for my QTabWidget. My tabs are movable and closable. For some reason, the tabs are not rendering when I try moving them.

[image: QTabWidget Before]

Here's what it looks like after I try moving one of them:

[image: QTabWidget After]

As you can see, the tab completely disappears. Am I missing something in my qss? Here is the stylesheet I'm using.

```
* {
    background-color: #3f4543;
    color: white;
    font-size: 12pt;
    margin: 0px;
    border: none;
}

QTabWidget::pane {
    border-top: 3px solid #535a57;
}

QTabWidget:movable {
    background: #ff7500;
}

QTabBar::tab {
    background: #535a57;
    min-width: 8ex;
    padding: 5px 10px;
}

    QTabBar::tab:hover {
        background: #6fc2ff;
    }

    QTabBar::tab:movable {
        background: #ff7500;
    }

    QTabBar::tab:selected {
        background: #0094ff;
    }

    QTabBar::tab:!selected {
        margin-top: 5px;
    }
```

I'm not sure if I'm covering all of the possible states, but I don't know which states the `::tab` subcontrol has. Thanks for your time looking at this!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Figured it out. It turns out that some of my application-wide styles were conflicting with the QTabWidget. I had to take out the `font-size`, `margin`, and `border` to get the bars to render correctly from the `* { }` block.

Comment: This hint really helped me. In my case, a `background-color` property in the `* { }` block was causing the issue. Removing it brought my custom tab style back to life on the movable tab.

Comment: It's been a long time since you answered your own question: if it actually solved your problem it would be nice to mark it as _accepted_, so it doesn't appear as an open question and people landing here can easily find the right answer.

Answer (score 1):

This was reported as a bug and has been solved in Qt 5.6. https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-45173

The problem is caused by application-wide setting background for QWidget:

```
QWidget {
  background: #afafaf;
}
```

Unfortunately I do not know any workaround other that not setting this. But, well, sometimes you need to have application-wide QWidget background and having invisible moving tabs is a lesser evil...